# Arrayformula that takes date (month and year) but ignores the formula when cell is blank

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I wanted to create a simple tracker using Google sheets that automatically inputs month and year from a reference cell (date) but I need to have it ignore the formula if the reference cell is empty.

Here's what I have, can someone correct this for me?

> =ARRAYFORMULA(MONTH(A1:A),IF(A1:A="",""))

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="",,TEXT(A1:A, "mm-yyyy")))
```